# Do all weeks of blocks take the same time to process?

Tags: blockchain, synchronization

Bitcoin is slowly synchronising

> Synchronising the  network... 78 weeks behind

Do all weeks of blocks take the same time to process? Or will recent blocks be slower because Bitcoin is more popular now?

It felt like going from '100 weeks behind' to '80 weeks behind' took longer than going from '200 weeks behind' to '100 weeks behind'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the number of transactions that counts. The progress bar in recent versions of the reference client (0.8.2 and higher) uses an estimation of this, so it represents real time better.

Also, after the last checkpoint (block 250000, as of 0.8.5), signature checking is enabled, which requires significantly more CPU to validate.

Comment: Thanks. Just got to block 250K and my computer has starting making a lot of noise.